# Redirect from old domain to new one (SEO friendly)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I changed the custom domain on my Heroku app to a new one. Now I will create a new Heroku app  which only purpose will be to redirect to the first app.

I read in Google Webmasters that I should do a 301 redirect like this:

```
http://old.com/anypath/123

to

http://new.com/anypath/123
```

How do I do it in Rails?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Put this in a before filter in the ApplicationControlller:

```ruby
class ApplicationController
  before_action :redirect_if_old

  protected

  def redirect_if_old
    if request.host == 'old.com'
      redirect_to "#{request.protocol}new.com#{request.fullpath}", :status => :moved_permanently 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @MartinPetrov, I updated my answer to show how to do all requests.

Comment: Note to anyone reading this today: request_uri is deprecated. Use `"#{request.protocol}new.com#{request.fullpath}"` instead of `"http://new.com#{request.request_uri}"`

Comment: As of Rails 5, should use `before_action` instead of `before_filter`.

Answer (score 5):

In your controller action:

```
redirect_to "http://new.com#{request.request_uri}", :status => 301
```

However, Heroku has what may be a [slightly better option](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#redirecting_traffic_to_a_specific_domain) for you documented in their dev center:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :ensure_domain

  APP_DOMAIN = 'myapp.mydomain.com'

  def ensure_domain
    if request.env['HTTP_HOST'] != APP_DOMAIN
      # HTTP 301 is a "permanent" redirect
      redirect_to "http://#{APP_DOMAIN}#{request.request_uri}", :status => 301
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. One question - will this redirect everything to the root of the new domain, or it will match the exact page in the new domain?

Comment: Updated. Ben beat me to it though.

Comment: Thank you too. Sorry for not being able to mark you answer too.

Comment: No worries, always happy with a +1 :)

Comment: This doesn't work in Rails 3.1 -- `request_uri` is gone.  Use `request.path` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the `routes.rb` file rather than a controller:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  constraints(host: 'old.com') do
    get '(*)', to: redirect(host: 'new.com')
  end

  # your existing routes here
end
```

This will do a 301 redirect, which is [the default for the redirect route helper](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection)