# Redirect old domain to new domain including subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I redirect all old domains like example.com, foo.example.com or bar.example.com/foo to new.com, foo.new.com or bar.new.com/foo in my Rails app?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is there [Redirect from old domain to new one (SEO friendly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578853/redirect-from-old-domain-to-new-one-seo-friendly)
Or alternatively you may do it using your web-server